# Is there a fast C or C++ standard library function for double precision inverse square root?

Tags: c++, c, double, sqrt

I find myself typing

```
double foo=1.0/sqrt(...);
```

a lot, and I've heard that modern processors have built-in inverse square root opcodes.

Is there a C or C++ standard library inverse square root function that

1. uses double precision floating point?
2. is as accurate as `1.0/sqrt(...)`?
3. is just as fast or faster than the result of `1.0/sqrt(...)`?

Comment: @Pherric Oxide: That was inverse square, not inverse square root.

Comment: #define INSQRT(x) (1.0/sqrt(x))

Comment: Must it work in "C **or** C++" or "C **and** C++"?

Comment: Is there a way you can rearrange the maths to do intermediate work in squares, then take a minimal number of square roots at the end?

Comment: The built-in inverse square root instruction that you've heard of is an approximation, not as exact as `sqrt`. See http://www.tommesani.com/SSEReciprocal.html

Comment: Not as fast as in [Quake III Arena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code) perhaps.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: That's basically the answer I was looking for.

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20900

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. No, there isn't. Not in C++. Nope.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function for faster inverse square root computing
There's an article on wikipedia on how it works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root
Also there's a C version of this algorithm.

```
float invSqrt( float number ){
    union {
        float f;
        uint32_t i;
    } conv;

    float x2;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    conv.f  = number;
    conv.i  = 0x5f3759df - ( conv.i >> 1 );
    conv.f  = conv.f * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * conv.f * conv.f ) );
    return conv.f;
}
```

Comment: Reading about this is what gave me the idea for the question. An article about the fast inverse square root said that some hardware had inverse square root instructions because of how much it comes up in graphics code. I couldn't use this algorithm at the time because I needed full double precision, but have an upvote for anyone reading this answer who hasn't heard of it :).

Comment: The "naive" version actually compiles down to fewer instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/aGWbP5qvs

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a standardized C API for this, but that does not mean you cannot use the fast inverse sqrt instructions, as long as you are willing to write **platform dependent intrinsics**.

Let's take 64-bit x86 with AVX for example, where you can use
[_mm256_rsqrt_ps()](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2,FMA&text=rsqrt&expand=4804) to approximate the reciprocal of a square root. Or more specifically: 8 square-roots in a single go, using SIMD.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

...

float inputs[8] = { ... } __attribute__ ((aligned (32)));
__m256 input = _mm256_load_ps(inputs);
__m256 invroot = _mm256_rsqrt_ps(input);
```

Similarly, you can use the intrinsic [vrsqrteq_f32](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491i/BABEHGDB.html) on ARM with NEON. In this case, the SIMD is 4-wide, so it will compute four inverse square roots in a single go.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

...

float32x4_t sqrt_reciprocal = vrsqrteq_f32(x);
```

Even if you need just one root value per batch, it is still faster than a full square root. Just set the input in all, or one lane of the SIMD register. That way, you will not have to go through your memory with a load operation. On x86 that is done via `_mm256_set1_ps(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Violating constraints 1. and 2. (and it's also not standard), but it still might help someone browsing through...

I used [ASMJIT](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) to just-in-time compile the exact assembly operation you're looking for: `RSQRTSS` (single precision, ok, but it should be similar with double).

My code is this (cf. also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622059/7302562) in a different post):

```
   typedef float(*JITFunc)();

   JITFunc func;
   asmjit::JitRuntime jit_runtime;
   asmjit::CodeHolder code;
   code.init(jit_runtime.getCodeInfo());

   asmjit::X86Compiler cc(&code);
   cc.addFunc(asmjit::FuncSignature0<float>());

   float value = 2.71; // Some example value.
   asmjit::X86Xmm x = cc.newXmm();
   uint32_t *i = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&value);
   cc.mov(asmjit::x86::eax, i[0]);
   cc.movd(x, asmjit::x86::eax);

   cc.rsqrtss(x, x);   // THE asm function.

   cc.ret(x);

   cc.endFunc();
   cc.finalize();

   jit_runtime.add(&func, &code);

   // Now, func() can be used as the result to rsqrt(value).
```

If you do the JIT compilation part only once, calling it later with different values, this should be faster (though slightly less accurate, but this is inherent to the built-in operations you're talking about) than `1.0/sqrt(...)`.

Answer (score -3):

If your not afraid of using your own functions, try the following:

```
template <typename T>
T invsqrt(T x)
{
    return 1.0 / std::sqrt(x);
}
```

It should be just as fast as the orginal `1.0 / std::sqrt(x)` in any modernly optimized compiler. Also, it can be used with doubles or floats.

Comment: violates rule#3 in the question!

Comment: Sorry, as I understand, it should be "just as fast".

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442358/do-c-templates-make-programs-slow to see why or why not template functions should be slower than non-templated code.

Comment: Also, if you enable `-ffast-math` in gcc, it will use an approximation to inverse square root. This would ensure it is just as fast/faster than regular square root.

Answer (score -5):

why not try this? `#define INSQRT(x) (1.0/sqrt(x))`

Its just as fast, requires less typing(makes you feel like its a function), uses double precision, as accurate as 1/sqrt(..)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but here's no use for a macro here when a function will do. (You even said it yourself: make it *feel* like a function? Just actually make a function.)

Comment: @GManNickG The reason I didn't convert it to a function is, because the question clearly mentions: "is just as fast or faster than the result of 1.0/sqrt(...)". Making it a function will add additional overhead making the "statement" 1.0/sqrt(...) SLOWER.

Comment: Not on any compiler from the last decade.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: Please provide benchmarks to back up your claim that using a real function will be slower. Macros may safely be avoided in the absence of evidence that they are required to meet some criterion. That said, I always carry my `#define isNaN(x) ((x)!=(x))` around with me; sometimes it just feels good to be so bad.

Answer (score -5):

If you find yourself writing the same thing over and over, you should think to yourself "function!":

```
double invsqrt(const double x)
{
    return 1.0 / std::sqrt(x);
}
```

Now the code is more self-documenting: people don't have to *deduce* `1.0 / std::sqrt(x)` is the inverse square root, they *read* it. Additionally, you now get to plug in whatever implementation you want and each call-site automatically uses the updated definition.

To answer your question, no, there is no C(++) function for it, but now that you've made one if you find your performance is too lacking you can substitute your own definition.

Comment: violates rule#3 in the question

Comment: why rely on the compiler when you can use the preprocessor? I still think I didn't deserve the -ve vote :-(

Comment: @PrototypeStark: Because it's not as simple as either-or. One is type-checked, debugabble, scopable, overloadable, evaluates its argument is an expression once, etc. (all the features of a function), the other is not. And it's a single downvote, it's not the end of the world; I understand it's frustrating not getting a reason from the person themselves, but that's how it is.

Comment: he just downvoted and left yeah its frustrating. I find it funny too though.

Comment: I would argue that it is easier to read `1.0/sqrt(x)` as the inverse square root than `invsqrt(x)`, the former using the less ambiguous mathematical notation as opposed to an abbreviation.

Comment: @Dan: That's fine, it's up to you what you find easy to read of course. But over time I think you'll find it's much better in principle to hide details, including what constitutes an inverse square root.

Comment: "inverse square root" just means the reciprocal of the square root, though. It's not a detail, it's literally what the function name means.

Comment: @Dan: You're conflating implementation with specification. You're right, inverse square root is the reciprocal of the square root, but how to do get from that to `1.0 / sqrt(x)`? It's not hard, of course, but that's not the point: it's still a division from specification to implementation. Hide the implementation, keep the specification; it makes reasoning and maintaining about your program easier. Consider how easy it would be to optimize *every single* inverse square root calculation in your entire program, just by changing the implementation and keeping the specification.

Comment: @GManNickG: While I'd usually be the first to agree with that logic, there are limits. You wouldn't write a function `multiplyByTwo` -- you'd write `*2`. Personally I'd say the inverse square root example is right on the borderline.