# Is returning a private class member slower than using a struct and accessing that variable directly?

Tags: c++, performance, class, struct

Suppose you have a class that has private members which are accessed a lot in a program (such as in a loop which has to be fast). Imagine I have defined something like this:

```
class Foo
{
public: 

    Foo(unsigned set)
        : vari(set)
    {}

    const unsigned& read_vari() const { return vari; }

private:
    unsigned vari;
};
```

The reason I would like to do it this way is because, once the class is created, "vari" shouldn't be changed anymore. Thus, to minimize bug occurrence, "it seemed like a good idea at the time".

However, if I now need to call this function millions of times, I was wondering if there is an overhead and a slowdown instead of simply using:

```
struct Foo
{
    unsigned vari;
};
```

So, was my first impule right in using a class, to avoid anyone mistakenly changing the value of the variable after it has been set by the constructor?
Also, does this introduce a "penalty" in the form of a function call overhead. (Assuming I use optimization flags in the compiler, such as -O2 in GCC)?

Comment: They are not the same. With the method you are returning a copy, so you can't really access the variable. The equivalent, read only version would be `const unsigned& read_vari() const { return vari; }`

Comment: @juanchopanza. Thank you for your message. I will update my question shortly.

Comment: In theory, without optimizations (particularly, inlining of your getter), yes. In practice, in a release build with the usual optimizations, both options will be compiled to the same assembly instructions. So yes, your impulse was right :)

Comment: You can check the assembly yourself and be 100% sure. Instead of hoping someone will know what your compiler does :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They should come out to be the same. Remember that frustrating time you tried to use the `operator[]` on a vector and `gdb` just replied `optimized out`? This is what will happen here. The compiler will not create a function call here but it will rather access the variable directly.

Let's have a look at the following code

```
struct foo{
   int x;
   int& get_x(){
     return x;
   }   
};

int direct(foo& f){ 
   return  f.x;
}

int fnc(foo& f){ 
   return  f.get_x();
}
```

Which was compiled with `g++ test.cpp -o test.s -S -O2`. The `-S` flag tells the compiler to "Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble (quote from the g++ manpage)." This is what the compiler gives us:

```
_Z6directR3foo:
.LFB1026:
  .cfi_startproc
  movl  (%rdi), %eax
  ret
```

and

```
_Z3fncR3foo:
.LFB1027:
  .cfi_startproc
  movl  (%rdi), %eax
  ret
```

as you can see, no function call was made in the second case and they are both the same. Meaning there is no performance overhead in using the accessor method.

**bonus: what happens if optimizations are turned off?** same code, here are the results:

```
_Z6directR3foo:
.LFB1022:
  .cfi_startproc
  pushq %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  .cfi_offset 6, -16
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
  movq  %rdi, -8(%rbp)
  movq  -8(%rbp), %rax
  movl  (%rax), %eax
  popq  %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
  ret
```

and

```
_Z3fncR3foo:
.LFB1023:
  .cfi_startproc
  pushq %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  .cfi_offset 6, -16 
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
  subq  $16, %rsp
  movq  %rdi, -8(%rbp)
  movq  -8(%rbp), %rax
  movq  %rax, %rdi
  call  _ZN3foo5get_xEv    #<<<call to foo.get_x()
  movl  (%rax), %eax
  leave
  .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
  ret
```

As you can see without optimizations, the sturct *is* faster than the accessor, but who ships code without optimizations?

Comment: Actually, you can ship code without optimizations if you wish, but at that point the function call overhead of a getter should be your last worry: all the templated code (STL/Boost) will be so slow that you won't even notice the rest.

Comment: @MatthieuM. what are you referring to? Templates do make compiling slower but [I have not heard of templates slowing down the actual execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442358/do-c-templates-make-programs-slow). Could you provide a source?

Comment: Actually, it's just a natural consequence of your answer: most of the STL & Boost piles up layers upon layers of template classes and functions. When you compile with optimizations on, those layers are folded together until barely any code remains so it's fast; however without optimizations each layer add its own function call overhead. Just look at the average `std::vector::push_back` implementation and you'll see exactly what I mean :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. ok never thought of it this way.

Answer (score 5):

You can expect *identical* performance.  A great many C++ classes rely on this - for example, C++11's `list::size() const` can be expected to trivially return a data member.  (Which contrasts with `vector()`, where the implementation's I've looked at calculate `size()` as the difference between pointer data member's corresponding to `begin()` and `end()`, ensuring typical iterator usage is as fast as possible at the cost of potentially slower indexed iteration, if the optimiser can't determine that `size()` is constant across loop iterations).

There's typically no particular reason to return by `const` reference for a type like `unsigned` that should fit in a CPU register anyway, but as it's inlined the compiler doesn't have to take that literally (for an out-of-line version it would likely be implemented by returning a pointer that has to be dereferenced).  (The atypical reason is to allow taking the address of the variable, which is why say `vector::operator[](size_t) const` needs to return a `const T&` rather than a `T`, even if `T` is small enough to fit in a register.)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to tell with certainty which one is faster *in your particular program built with your particular tools with your particular optimisation flags on your particular platform* — by *measuring* both variants.

Having said that, chances are good that the binaries will be identical, instruction for instruction.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, optimizers these days are relied on to boil out abstraction (especially in C++, which is more or less built to take advantage of that) and they're very, very good.

But you might not need the getter for this.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(unsigned set) : vari(set) {}
    unsigned const vari;
};
```

`const` doesn't forbid initialization.